# QT Android application crashes when Back Button pressed while running MDM in Kiosk Mode

Tags: android, qt, mdm

Anyone have any experience with integrating Android Mobile Device Management solutions with their QT Application? I’ve been vetting one vendor but my application freezes every time I hit the Back Button while my application is in Kiosk Mode. I thought the issue was specific to my application but I built a trivial Android QT application from the ground up and sure enough I ran into the same issue. Do you know any solutions? Are their just some Android MDMs that work better with QT than others?

Answer (score 0):

By default, clicking Back finishes the activity, and it's up to the MDM what's going further.

I would expect restarting the kiosk mode activity (we do that in our Headwind MDM), but the MDM you're using may behave differently.

I would recommend simply blocking the Back button from finishing the activity by overriding `onBackPressed()`.